# Artifact not being downloaded in release pipeline - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been struggling with an issue in Azure DevOps where I can build successfully an artifact through a build pipeline (I use the publish artifact task). I can see that the artifact is built successfully, as I can download it and I can reference it later in the release pipeline.

The issue is that when the hosted agent is started, no artifacts are downloaded to the machine, and my $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) is always empty. I am out of ideas on why in the initialization of the hosted agent, no artifacts are actually being downloaded....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same issue this week. I set up my build with the 'Publish pipeline artifact' task and ran into the same issue as you, i replaced this with 'Publish build artifact' task in my build and everything worked out then.

I've read that 'Publish pipeline artifact' is only intended for uploading/downloading artifacts within the same pipeline, so thats why this won't get downloaded automatically in your release. Alternatively you could use the 'Download Pipeline Artifact' task in your release to explicitly download your artifact

Comment: Man you rock, that was exactly the issue. Thank you so much, I didn't even notice that "Publish pipeline artifact" and "Publish build artifact" were two different things.

Comment: I thought Publish pipeline artifact was the preferred way to copy artifacts between build and release instead of "Publish build artifact", which seems to be deprecated according to MS docs

Comment: @Alex that is correct, "publish pipeline artifact" is now the preferred way to copy artifacts, at the time of writing this issue this task was new and a bit more limited and not yet a full replacement of the "old" "publish build artifact"-task

Comment: This implies that you can't have seperate pipleines.... a CI pipeline that buidls everytime and a CD pipleine that deploys much less regularly

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid you can but it requires pulling in the CI pipeline as a "resource" to be able to reference the artifacts it creates. See the answer to a similar question as an example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65660845/3794873 .

Comment: Thanks. After a lot of reading and experimenting I worked it out.