# Azure Pipelines DownloadPipelineArtifact is not downloading artifacts

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a CI pipeline that generates an artifact called 'build-artifact'. I publish this artifact with the publish step:

```yaml
- publish: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
  artifact: build-artifact
```

I can see that the pipelines publishes the artifact correctly.
Then in a different pipeline I try to download the artifact as is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema)

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 'cipipeline'
      source: "receiver-ci"

steps:
- download: cipipeline
  artifact: build-artifact
```

I expect this to download the artifact. Instead, it sees all the files but does not download them. This is the output from running the above pipeline:

```
Starting: Download
==============================================================================
Task         : Download pipeline artifact
Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
Version      : 1.2.5
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
==============================================================================
Download from the specified build: #27608
Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/cipipeline/build-artifact
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 5a3786ae-b9b7-42ff-bae1-be29821e4d0f
DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 5a3786ae-b9b7-42ff-bae1-be29821e4d0f
Minimatch patterns: [**]
Filtered 24 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.
Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (0%).
Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (100%).

Download statistics:
Total Content: 0.0 MB
Physical Content Downloaded: 0.0 MB
Compression Saved: 0.0 MB
Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
Chunks Downloaded: 24
Nodes Downloaded: 0

Download completed.
ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 5a3786ae-b9b7-42ff-bae1-be29821e4d0f
```

What is happening? Why won't azure download the artifacts?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Sorry I completely forgot to answer this. I fixed it using thing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089900/artifact-not-being-downloaded-in-release-pipeline-azure-devops. So I'll be closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

This artifact has been downloaded and saved in `/home/vsts/work/1/cipipeline/build-artifact`. We could add task `Publish Pipeline Artifacts` and check it.

Sample:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 'cipipeline'
      source: "receiver-ci"

steps:
- download: cipipeline
  artifact: build-artifact

- publish: /home/vsts/work/1/cipipeline/build-artifact
  artifact: test
```

In addition, If the Artifact is less than 1MB, maybe you could see the message `Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (100%)`.

My test result:

[image]

Comment: I think the `Filtered 6 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.` is also confusing, because the filter means "grabbed" not "ignored". After doing a `ls -la ..` or `gci .. -recurse` I realized that I had been using the wrong "working directory" variable to set the path to the artifacts when I stumbled across this helpful answer.